Почему при копировании в другой проект, webpack bundle.js работает только при полном переносе файла?
Я собираю bundle.js с помощью Webpack, чтобы использовать данный бандл в другом проекте.
Если я копирую содержимое bundle.js и вставляю в пустой bundle.js в другом проекте, он не работает (код выдает Class undefined).
Если я полностью переношу файл bundle.js, то всё работает.
Сталкивался ли кто-то с таким случаем и почему такое может быть (или так и должно быть)?
Источник: https://github.com/editor-js/personality
